# PHP generate random password

Tags: php

I have put together this little script which uses a list of words to generate a readable password.

The first part of the code works fine by generating the word and number. The problem is with the symbols at the end only seems to work every so often.

```
 <?php
function random_readable_pwd($length=10){

    // the wordlist from which the password gets generated 
    // (change them as you like)
    $words = 'AbbyMallard,AbigailGabble,AbisMal,Abu,Adella,TheAgent,AgentWendyPleakley,Akela,AltheAlligator,Aladar,Aladdin,AlamedaSlim,AlanaDale,Alana,Alcmene,Alice,AmeliaGabble,AmosSlade,Amphitryon,AnastasiaTremaine,Anda,Andrina,Angelique,AngusMacBadger';

    // Split by ",":
    $words = explode(',', $words);
    if (count($words) == 0){ die('Wordlist is empty!'); }

    // Add words while password is smaller than the given length
    $pwd = '';
    while (strlen($pwd) < $length){
        $r = mt_rand(0, count($words)-1);
        $pwd .= $words[$r];
    }

    $num = mt_rand(1, 99);
     if ($length > 2){
        $pwd = substr($pwd,0,$length-strlen($num)).$num;
    } else { 
        $pwd = substr($pwd, 0, $length);
    }

   $pass_length = strlen($pwd);
   $random_position = rand(0,$pass_length);

   $syms = "!@#$%^&*()-+?";
   $int = rand(0,51);
   $rand_char = $syms[$int];

   $pwd = substr_replace($pwd, $rand_char, $random_position, 0);

    return $pwd;
}


?>
<html><head><title>Password generator</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Password generator</h2>

<p>
<?php 
echo random_readable_pwd(10);
?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: replace `rand()` with `mt_rand()`. The first one is know for generating extremely poor randomness.

Comment: `mt_rand()` is also a poor choice for cryptographic use. Use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead. See note at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#refsect1-function.mt-rand-notes

Comment: OpenSSL is also usually a poor choice for cryptographic use [#1](https://externals.io/message/103345) [#2](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/96) [#3](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/5). Instead, use `random_bytes` or `random_int` if you’re on PHP 7+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you seem to be getting a random number between 0 and 51, but there are only 13 characters in the $syms string. It should be:

```
$syms = "!@#$%^&*()-+?";
$int = rand(0,12);
$rand_char = $syms[$int];
```

Haven't tested this, but I think this is the issue.

Or even better, get the [string's length](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
$syms = "!@#$%^&*()-+?";
$int = rand(0,strlen($syms)-1);
$rand_char = $syms[$int];
```